# ¿Cómo ver qué constantes tiene definidas una clase en PHP?

Tags: php, get, constantes

Tengo una clase definida `A` que hereda de `Letra` y tiene una constante que modifica el comportamiento de un método que hereda de dicha clase.

Esa constante `CUSTOM` es opcional y no está definida en la clase `B` que también hereda de `Letra`.

Pero si dentro del método se intenta comprobar si está definida `isset(B::CUSTOM)` se obtiene un error `Undefined constant B::CUSTOM`.

¿Cómo se puede solucionar este problema sin tener que sobrescribir el método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) se usa para saber si una variable (o índice) está declarada, pero tú la estás usando para constantes.

La función [defined()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.defined.php) es la adecuada para comprobar constantes, enviando la constante como cadena, entre comillas y anteponiendo el nombre de la clase:

```
if(defined('B::CUSTOM')) {
    echo 'La constante CUSTOM está definida en B';
}
```

Comment: Ah, pensaba que sólo servía para constantes globales, no había visto ningún ejemplo en el que lo usaran así en la documentación. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución sería definir el siguiente método en la clase `Letra`:

```
  // class Letra
  public static function getConstants() {
    $refl = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
    $constantes = array_keys($refl->getConstants());
    return $constantes;
  }
```

Y luego, dentro del otro, comprobar si está definida la constante `CUSTOM` de la siguiente manera:

```
public function hacerAlgo(){
  $algo = in_array("CUSTOM", $this::getConstants()) ? $this::CUSTOM : Letra::DEFAULT;
  ...
}
```